# If the derivative of $f(x)$ w.r.t. $ x$ is $\frac{\cos x}{f(x)} $ then show that $f(x)$ is periodic.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If the derivative of $f(x)$ w.r.t. $x$ is $\frac{\cos x}{f(x)} $ then show that $f(x)$ is periodic.

The only information we have is $$f'(x)=\frac{\cos x}{f(x)}  $$ and we want to prove that $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for some $T$.
From where should I start ?

Answer (score 8):

Note that you can rearrange the equation as

$$f'(x) f(x) = \cos x$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)^2 = 2 \cos x$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: it should be 2 instead of $\frac 12$ in your answer

Comment: @user26977 Quite right, thanks for the correction.